# Completely rotate and randomize all DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, random

I have an "interesting" client, a painter, who wants to throw users for a loop on his website.

They're looking to add a fake username and password form on their site which will so something really funky to confuse the user. There is no point to this form, he just wants to do it for fun.

It shouldn't make the page go completely blank, or else it looks unintentionally broken. He's hoping to make it look *intentionally* broken.

I was hoping to make the DOM elements melt/fall down to the bottom of the page, swirl in a hurricane like fashion, or just something that is comical and out of place.

I'm not sure if a library exists that can already do any of that, so I started by randomly rotating and realigning all the elements on the website (everything in the DOM) to a randomized absolute position and randomly rotated.

```
jQuery( function($)
{
    jQuery( 'input[type="submit"]' ).on( 'click', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery( "*" ).each(function()
        {
            rotateX = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
            rotateY = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
            rotateZ = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
            positionX = Math.floor((Math.random() * (window.innerWidth/2) + 1);
            positionY = Math.floor((Math.random() * (window.innerHeight/2) + 1);

            if (
                $(this).context.tagName != 'HTML' &&
                $(this).context.tagName != 'BODY' &&
                $(this).context.tagName != 'HEAD'
            )
            $(this).css({
                transform: "rotate3d("+rotateX+","+rotateY+","+rotateZ+")",
                position: "absolute",
                top: positionY,
                right: positionX
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It works okay, not so well in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lenuqaqi/1/edit), but it confusing to the user as to what it is doing and isn't comical.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to slow the animation down, a funnier script I can use or a library that already has these sort of DOM randomizing effects?

Comment: Confusing users is a great way to retain visitors to a site. Your client is pure genius.

Comment: http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google-gravity/

Comment: "slow the animation down"

there's no animation currently

Comment: @xxbbcc he's pretty eccentric, yet well known. He needs a website to advertise his exhibitions but wants to add some of his personality to the site.

Comment: @adeneo, that's exactly what I'm looking for, hopefully it's MIT licensed. Thank you.

Comment: @guest that's right, I'd probably have to use setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

Such CSS should do the trick:

```
*{
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}
```